# Join array of numbers with table in function

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I need some support with array type, because it is a new thing for me, so

I have a function:

```
create or replace type num_array as table of number;

create or replace function functionname(arr_in num_array) 
return num_array is
tab num_array;
begin
select id_acc bulk collect into tab from (
    SELECT a.id_acc
      FROM (SELECT id_acc, parent_acc FROM account) a
      connect by nocycle prior a.id_acc=a.parent_acc
      start with id_acc in 
      (
        select distinct ID_ACC
        from (SELECT id_acc, parent_acc FROM account 
      ) a
      where parent_acc = id_acc
      connect by nocycle prior a.parent_acc = a.id_acc or parent_acc is null 
      start with id_acc in (select parent_acc from table_name t,account a where t.id=a.id_acc)));

return tab;
end;
```

As an input I want to have an array of numbers (id). I want to connect that number (from input) with account table. It is in line:

```
start with id_acc in (select parent_acc from table_name t,account a where t.id=a.id_acc)));
```

I would like to join somehow table account with numbers from input,
I was trying to use table(tab()),account a but I got an error. 
As output I would like to have result of select query so (return tab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you want to achieve. Just to help you with the syntax, look at this:

```
start with id_acc in (select * from table(arr_in));
```

Comment: I want to join table(arr_in) with account table.

Comment: Something like that select parent_acc from table(arr_in) t,account a where t.column_value=a.id_acc, but it is not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Not giving the expected result or a error message (then paste it here).

Comment: Once again: I'm trying to connect table with array.  And finally it works: ) it should be: start with id_acc in (select parent_acc from table(arr_in) t,account a where t.column_value=a.id_acc))); .

Comment: Of course I meant : select parent_acc from account where id_acc in (select * from table(arr_in))).

Answer (score 0):

Below i have provided a small snippet which basically illustrates your issue with joining Nested Table type with Table.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_ntt_join
      RETURN NUMBER_NTT
    AS
      lv_tab_num NUMBER_NTT;
      lv_tab2 NUMBER_NTT;
    BEGIN
      SELECT LEVEL BULK COLLECT INTO lv_tab_num FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;
        SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
        BULK COLLECT INTO 
        lv_tab2
        FROM TABLE(lv_tab_num) t,
          EMP
        WHERE emp.empno= t.column_value;
      RETURN lv_tab2;
    END;


------------------------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------------
select * from table(test_ntt_join);

COLUMN_VALUE
1
1
3

------------------------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------------
```